# Regex to count words after an underscored word

Tags: python, regex

I want to count an unknown number of words in a string that appear after an underscored word.

```
testString='21 High Street _Earth Mighty Motor Mechanic'
```

I can match these words using a non-capture group `(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)` But cannot build the regex up to eliminate what comes before the underscored word from the match. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULGx0d/1)

I was looking to use the completed pattern in a Python script as follows:

```
import re
pattern = r'(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)'
results = re.findall(pattern, testString)
if results:
  answer = len(results)
```

Comment: Does it need to be RegEx or is a non-RegEx python solution acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Extracting Words Following an Underscore in a Text String

To capture the words after an underscored word in a string, excluding the underscored word itself, you can utilize the [following regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/NObxz6/1):

```py
_\w+\s([\w\s]+)
```

This regular expression operates as follows:

- `_\w+\s` matches the underscored word along with the subsequent space.
- `([\w\s]+)` then captures a sequence of word characters and spaces.

In practical application, this regular expression can be implemented in Python as follows:

```py
import re

testString = '21 High Street _Earth Mighty Motor Mechanic'
pattern = r'_\w+\s([\w\s]+)'

match = re.search(pattern, testString)
if match:
    words_after = match.group(1).split()
    count = len(words_after)
    print(f"Number of words after the underscored word: {count}")
else:
    print("No underscored word found or no words after it.")
```

### Extracting Words Starting From an Underscored Word in a Text String

If your goal is to include the underscored word in the count, you can modify the [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/dbGoqr/1) slightly:

```py
(_\w+\s[\w\s]+)
```

This version functions in the following way:

- `(_\w+\s[\w\s]+)` captures both the underscored word and all subsequent words. Here, `_\w+` matches the underscored word, and `\s[\w\s]+` accounts for the following space and words.

The implementation in Python would be:

```py
import re

testString = '21 High Street _Earth Mighty Motor Mechanic'
pattern = r'(_\w+\s[\w\s]+)'

match = re.search(pattern, testString)
if match:
    words = match.group(1).split()
    count = len(words)
    print(f"Total number of words including the underscored word: {count}")
else:
    print("No underscored word found or no words after it.")
```

**NOTE:** The choice between these two regular expressions depends on whether you want to include the underscored word in your word count.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the below regex:

```
(?<=_)\w+\s+(.*)
```

**Explanation of above regex:**

1. ***`(?<=_)`*** - Represents *[positive lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)* asserting what immediately precedes the current position in the string is `_`.
2. ***`\w+`*** - Matches one or more word(`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) characters.
3. ***`\s+`*** - Matches 1 or more whitespace characters.
4. ***`(.*)`*** - Capturing group matching anything.
   [image]

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/hfje1Q/2)
[Sample code](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zyaupzck)

---

#### Alternative solution:

```py
testString = '21 High Street _Earth Mighty Motor Mechanic'
# split on whitespace
words = testString.split()
# generator expression to find first underscored word
underscored_word = next((word for word in words if '_' in word), None)
# find number of word after underscored word
answer = len(words[words.index(underscored_word) + 1:]) if underscored_word else 0
print(answer)
# Overall time complexity of the code is O(n) + 2 * O(m) ~ O(n)
# n: length of testString
# m: number of words in the testString.
```

[Sample code](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zyaw5nvd)